# getLatitude() / getLongitide() stopped working after Android 12 upgrade

Tags: android, location

Originally working perfectly on all versions before Android 12:

```
var lat = 0;
var lon = 0;
...
    var locationListener = new LocationListener({
    onLocationChanged: function(location) {
        lat = location.getLatitude().toFixed(4);
        lon = location.getLongitude().toFixed(4);
...
```

stopped working after upgrade to Android 12 with the following error:

> At line XX: TypeError: Cannot find function getLatitude in object
> [Location[network 12.345678,12.345678 hAcc=12.345 et=+1d23h56m12s345ms
> alt=123.45678 vAcc=1.2345 {Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=68]}]].

So the object looks fine and has a valid data (so no questions about permissions), but somehow it cannot parse the Lat/Long from it. I don't see any changes in API documentation.

I must say I'm launching it via a "bridge" in app that allows me to run Java and/or Javascript code. Something like task in Tasker, where you can run a script.

Comment: Not working? Or not available? A compile time error?

Comment: It almost works, meaning it just can not fetch the Lat/Lon and throws this error. But I see correct data in object. I just replaced my actual ccordinates with 12.123456 in this post.

What I can do, I can stringify the object and parse it as text, but...

Comment: `but somehow it cannot parse the Lat/Long from it.` Well that is not the message. The message is dat member function getLatitude() is not found. The message is also not that they stopped working. These 1234567 replacements are terrible. You could put coordinates of a town in it. And a real date. And not equal lat and lon.

Comment: Which version do you mean,? Of device or app or what?

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean - the code (in general) cannot parse the Lat/Long because the member function could not be found.

Comment: Android version 12 API 31, what else can I say? This code was working on all Android versions below 12 / API 31.

Comment: Repeat: Which version do you mean,? Of device or app or what? –

Comment: Version of Android. Device is the same. App is the same. Code is the same. Only Android version has changed due to upgrade.

Comment: Sorry, i do not understand your explanation.